# Parse (possibly empty) text and variable definitions inside brackets

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I'm trying to parse an input into text and variable items. The input may be empty, have only text items, only variable items, or a mix of them.

The following is some sample input:

```
<>
<a text>
<an escaped \< and an escaped \>>
<${aVar}>
<a text and ${aVar}>
<${aVar} and a text>
<a text ${aVar} ${someMoreVars} and more text>
```

I tried to parse it with the following grammar:

```
grammar Translation;

file : ( translation | comment)* EOF ;

translation : '<' ( text | varDef )* '>' ;

varDef : '${' VARDEF '}';

text : TEXT ;
```

But whatever I tried for the `TEXT` rule, I either end up parsing everything as `text` or I get the nasty problem

> non-fragment lexer rule TEXT can match the empty string

Which sends me straight on to a stack overflow.

How can I solve the problem?  Do I have to go to an 'island grammar'? I can't see how that would help.

The problem can't be this hard to solve but I am really stuck now.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post your entire grammar, so I cannot tell you what exactly is wrong with your grammar. You can however do something like this to parse your input:

```
file
 : ( translation | COMMENT )* EOF
 ;

translation : '<' ( text | var_def )* '>' ;

text
 : TEXT+
 ;

var_def
 : VAR_DEF_START text VAR_DEF_END
 ;

COMMENT
 : '//' ~[\r\n]*
 ;

SPACES
 : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
 ;
VAR_DEF_START
 : '${'
 ;

VAR_DEF_END
 : '}'
 ;

TEXT
 : '\\' [\\<>]
 | ~[\\<> \t\r\n]
 ;
```

It is important to match single (!) `TEXT` characters in the lexer, and "glue" them together inside the `text` parser rule. If you try to match multiple `TEXT` chars in the lexer, you will end up matching too much characters.

Comment: Hello Bart, thank you for the invaluable time you have spent to answer my question.
The key insight I had is that I have 'to match single (!) TEXT characters'.
Missleaded by the examples for COMMENT or STRING, I always tried to match the text with some sort of nongreedy expression (.*?) which always matched to much text.
I fear I have to switch to an 'Island grammer' because the new  TEXT token interfears with my WS and COMMENT tokens.
Again, thanks a lot for your help.